# Scrapy: Removing line Feeds /n from list

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm an absolute newbie considering scrapy/python and even programming, but I need to learn and understand it. I have created a small spider, which crawls a website and extracts some information from the website and aggregates it into a csv file. So far I have gotten a rather succesfull output, however, I have a problem with the site content itself. The xpath selector for the sitecontent item yields the content as a list; however I want it to turn it into a single string free of line feeds etc. I know, that normalized-space and strip() will be the way to go, however they only remove the leading/trailing line feeds, resulting in `['']` as the output. I have diffculties to implement a loop into the code,which iterates over the list and puts together a string in the end, which can be saved properly in the csv. Anyone able to help me?

Here's the spider:

```py
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "nbtest"
    allowed_domains = ['norisbank.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.norisbank.de']

    custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': "norisbank_%(time)s.csv",
                      'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
                      }

     def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'nbtest-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

        #Content Extraction
        print(response.url)
        sitename = response.xpath("//meta[@property='og:site_name']/@content")[0].getall()
        siteurl = response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical']/@href")[0].getall()
        dbCategory = response.xpath("//meta[@name='dbCategory']/@content")[0].getall()
        titles = response.css('title::text').extract()
        descriptions = response.xpath("//meta[@name='description']/@content")[0].getall()
        date = response.xpath("//meta[@name='date']/@content")[0].getall()
        version = response.xpath("//meta[@name='v']/@content")[0].getall()
        time = response.xpath("//meta[@name='time']/@content")[0].getall()
        sitecontent = response.xpath('//body//p//text()').extract()

        #Sort extracted conten in rows
        for item in zip(sitename,siteurl,dbCategory,titles,descriptions,date,version,time,sitecontent):

            scraped_info = {
                'sitename' : item[0],
                'siteurl' : item[1],
                'dbCategory' : item [2],
                'title' : item [3],
                'description' : item [4],
                'date' : item [5],
                'version' : item [6],
                'time' : item [7],
                'sitecontent' : item [8]
            }

            yield scraped_info

        all_pages = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "html")]/@href').getall()
        for next_page in all_pages :
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ItemLoaders which will put your values into a list however,something called an output processor can be applied called Join() to convert a list into a string.

See [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)

### ItemLoaders

Itemloaders are a convenient and slightly more concise way of grabbing data from the response than items or yielding a dictionary. The beauty of an ItemLoader class is that it gives you access to input and output processors which allow you to modify the data before and after inputting into the item dictionary with scrapy's builtin methods. But even better, it allows you to create your own methods/functions so that each item can be modified however which way you like.

So instead of using items, we instantiate an itemloader class. This puts data collected using xpath/css and adds these to a list associated with the item field. The benefit of this is that any cleaning or changing of the data within the item dictionary.

### Example

Within your scrapy spider script

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader 
from ..item import XXXItem 

def parse(self,response):
   l = ItemLoader(item=XXXItem(), response=response)
   l.add_xpath('field_name1','//div[@class="name"]')
   l.add_xpath('field_name2','//div[@class="title"]')
   yield l.load_item()
```

We specify the item class as the first argument in the itemloader and the response. We then use the add_xpath method to define the item field name and the xpath to get the data we want and the use the load_item() method to populate the item dictionary.

No need for extract() or get() you can just input the item field name and the xpath and it will populate that field. You can add as many values to each field name, Itemloaders populates a list per item field.

Within items.py

```
class XXXItem(Item): 
    field_name1 = scrapy.Field()
    field_name2 = scrapy.Field()
```

Now you asked about changing a list you have extracted, now scrapy allows you to do this with ItemLoaders and the Join() method. See [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.Join)

Within items.py

```
class XXXItem(Item): 
    field_name1 = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Join())
    field_name2 = scrapy.Field()
```

We define within the field method the output_processor, any item will then be processed by the Join method. In the case of a single value in a list, this does the equivalent of "".join(field_name1).

So say you had a list of one item, it will convert this into a string.

It would be worth your time reading up on this functionality, as although your question to change a list into a string is slightly like a hammer to solve a problem, ItemLoaders can be very useful for more complex data modifying and gives you much more flexibility than yielding a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

So Armin here's the code

#### Spider Script

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import NorisbankItem

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "nbtest"
    allowed_domains = ['norisbank.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.norisbank.de']
    custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': "norisbank_%(time)s.csv",
                  'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
                  }

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'nbtest-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

    #Content Extraction
        print(response.url)

        l = ItemLoader(NorisbankItem(), response=response)

        l.add_xpath('sitename', "//meta[@property='og:site_name']/@content")
        l.add_xpath('siteurl', "//link[@rel='canonical']/@href")
        l.add_xpath('dbCategory',"//meta[@name='dbCategory']/@content")
        l.add_css('title','title::text')
        l.add_xpath('descriptions',"//meta[@name='description']/@content")
        l.add_xpath('date',"//meta[@name='date']/@content")
        l.add_xpath('version',"//meta[@name='v']/@content")
        l.add_xpath('time',"//meta[@name='time']/@content")
        l.add_xpath('sitecontent','//body//p//text()')
        yield l.load_item()

        all_pages = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "html")]/@href').getall()
        for next_page in all_pages:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I've taken down the code involving items. Anything involving modifying the data I always use item loaders. You can see we need to import ItemLoader and the Item Class in the spider. We instantiate the itemloader class, we have to define the item class to populate it and make sure itemloader can use response so that we can select XPATH on that response.

We then use the method add_xpath(), the first argument defines the item field in items.py, and the second argument is the xpath. Notice how we don't have to do get(). If there are multiple values attached to that xpath, itemloaders will put them in a list. Infact that is exactly what Itemloaders does it puts the data into a list regardless of whether it's one value or more. This list then populates the item dictionary. We have to yield the load_item method to populate that item dictionary at the end. Not too different but more compact and concise.

#### Items

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item,Field
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose,Join

def clean(x):

    if x:
        return x

class NorisbankItem(Item):
     define the fields for your item here like:
     name = scrapy.Field()
     sitename = scrapy.Field()
     siteurl = scrapy.Field()
     dbCategory = scrapy.Field()
     title = scrapy.Field()
     descriptions = scrapy.Field()
     date = scrapy.Field()
     version = scrapy.Field()
     time= scrapy.Field()
     sitecontent = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(str.strip,clean),
                                output_processor=Join(' '))
```

Here in items.py, we define the item fields. The sitecontent this is where we apply the input and output processors that give itemloaders their power. To use the input/output processor there are several ways, I find the way in the code  the simplest. Input processors are used to alter data before the data is populated in the item dictionary. Here we use MapCompose, this takes all values, and passes it to a function/method we specify, here we using a stripping string method we are stripping the string and then passing each value to the clean function.

This clean function is our own, again the other power of Itemloaders. Simply we want to return the values as along as they are not empty, i.e not ''. Remember this will be put into a list of values that is what Itemloader does as it populates the item dictionary. Here in the outprocessor we take each value in the list and we join it, seperating it by a space.

#### Other Thoughts

Try not to mix up CSS selectors and XPATH selectors when using itemloaders or indeed any scrapy script. I prefer xpath selectors as you have more flexability. If you don't want to use itemloaders or the script does not call for it use get() and getall() instead of extract() it's just quicker and bit more concise.

Comment: Aaron, thank you s much! It not only works like a charm, but now I understand the thoughts behind this clearly! I had some misunderstandings with item.py, so my fistr tries went down the drain! You are a very good tutor, so thank you again!

Comment: Thanks Armin for those kind words. 
Whilst reading back my respoonse another reason to use get() and getall() is that extract() doesn't necessarily always give you a string, sometimes it will give you a list and it's not clear when either situation occurs. This is why in the scrapy docs get() and getall() are recommended, get() will always give you a string, getall() will give you a list of values.

Comment: Another good hint! extract() drived me crazy in my first attempts, and I couldn't understand when a list was th putput and when a sting - I supposed, it was because of a special combiantion of special chars in the source. Then moved to get/getall whereever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, thank you very much for your answer and taling the time to enlighten me. The ItemLoaders seem a very good method to improve my spider, and I think (!) I have understood how they work. But in the first step, I'd like to get the current crawler working, and for this, I fear, I haven't understood correctly, how to embedd the ItemLoaders/join in my code - my tries have only resulted in errors - as said, I'm very new on this, frankly, I'm working with python and scrappy for abou a week now. The current result for my siteconten item looks like this: '\ n' 'texttextext' '\n' '\n' 'text2text2' etc. What I want is to convert this into: 'texttexttext text2text2'. So the questions are: Will the Itemloaders remove the line feeds, and, how, in concrete, do I get them with my current code working?